# Need Help with Pool Plug

Tags: electrical

The plug/electrical for my pool is connected to one circuit breaker.  I bought a new pump that only needs a regular outlet with a ground.  Does it have to be a GFI outlet if it's got it's own circuit breaker?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**

> **NEC 2014**
>
> **— SWIMMING POOLS, FOUNTAINS, AND SIMILAR INSTALLATIONS**
>
> **680.21 Motors.**
>
> C) GFCI Protection. Outlets supplying pool pump motors connected to single-phase, 120-volt through 240-volt branch drains, whether by receptacle or by direct connection, shall be provided with ground-fault circuit-interrupter protection for personnel.

Check with your local inspections department for any requirements that they may have.

Comment: @Tester101, thx but I can't find the code that requires the single yoke twist lock receptacle.  Can you please share.  Thx

Comment: Probably smart.  Thx for the update.

Comment: @Tester101 But you can use a GFCI breaker feeding the specialized receptacle.

Comment: @bib Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Just a point of interest. Under the 2014 NEC the "Employ a locking configuration" requirement in 680.22(A) was removed. Many places are already under the 2014 NEC so it's worth a check. Also, this twist-lock requirement was only for pump motor receptacles in the 2011 NEC.